# mysql query running slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Is there a way to speed up this query. Its loading slow and its about 279 records. I've indexed the Language & id field in the data. Is there anything else I can do?

```
echo "<select name=language style='width: 136px;'>";
echo "<option value=$language selected=selected>-- Select --</option>";
$group1 = '<optgroup label=Common>';
$group2 = '<optgroup label=Alphabetically>';
$group = mysql_query("SELECT language, grouping, p_order FROM lang_list 
            WHERE grouping IN ('1','2') ORDER BY p_order");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($group))
{
  if ($row['grouping'] == '1')
  {
       $group1 .= '<option value="'.$row['language'].'">'.
            $row['language'].'</option>';
  }
  else
  {
       $group2 .= '<option value="'.$row['language'].'">'.
            $row['language'].'</option>';
  }
    $group1 .= '</otpgroup>';
    $group2 .= '</otpgroup>';

    echo $group1;
    echo $group2;
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Table

```
lang_list (
  id int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  language varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  grouping varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  p_order varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id, language)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=280 ;
```

Comment: Can you post the query execution plan for the above query?

Comment: post the output of the `EXPLAIN` of the query, just add `EXPLAIN` to the beginning

Comment: How much time is the query taking? There are very few records and no joins at all. It should get fixed with the proper indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to index what you are
>   matching against.

Just like in a book, page number of all chapters are given in the index because readers search by chapter, similarly for Mysql to process your queries faster, you need to index the fields  which will be matched in the where condition. Index the fields which others have suggested here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to index also `grouping` and `p_order`. You can drop index on `language` if not used by any where condition.

Please post the table schema for further investigation, and some sample data.

Comment: i've added it to my original post

Comment: Ok cool, now add the indexes I mentioned, and see how performs

Answer (score 1):

```
create index I_grouping_order on lang_list (grouping, p_order);
```

If you want to know the details have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Note that adding two separate indexes (one for `grouping` and one for `p_order`) will not completelly do the trick because you are using both fields in your query at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try a compossed index on groupping and p_order. Read more about  [group by optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html)